# Auto restart Quarkus Microservice after broker unavailability

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye

I have a very simple Quarkus microservice which uses smallrye reactive messaging (kafka). Sometimes my kafka broker goes down and I got the following logs :

```
2020-09-24 04:04:27,067 WARN [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:2202 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected 2020-09-24 04:04:27,083 WARN [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-3) [Producer clientId=producer-3] Connection to node -1 (xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.fr/XX.XX.XX.XXX:2202) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

After the broker has been restarted, I have to manually restart my microservice. Is it possible to add to capability to the microservice to reconsume the new incoming messages without any manual action?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using KafkaProducer and Consumer API they automatically reconnect once the broker is up again.
Please ensure that in your application you do not throw an exception and kill the thread. If you keep the thread alive then it will reconnect. Catch all exceptions for Consumer thread to ensure it is not exiting due to a runtime exception.

Comment: simply add on the method signature @OnOverflow(value = OnOverflow.Strategy.DROP)